# MVC - View will not display

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I have a view I cannot get to display in MVC
Here is my Controller Code:

```
public class ReconController : Controller

{
    static List<Recon> _recon = new List<Recon>();
    public ActionResult Load()
    {    
        _recon = GetList();

        return View("Load",_recon);
    }

    private List<Recon> GetList()
    {
        List<Recon> _pvtrecon = new List<Recon>();
        string sSource = "Test";
        string sClinicID = "4";
        string sAccountName = "Checking";
        string sStatus = null;
        ReconUIDataLayer.Reconciliation reconlist = new     ReconUIDataLayer.Reconciliation();
        reconlist = ReconUIDataLayer.UIDataLayer.LoadRecon(sSource, sClinicID, sAccountName, ref sStatus);



        _pvtrecon = (from rows in reconlist.LineItems
                 select new Recon
                 {
                     ClinicID = rows.ClinicID.ToString(), //Convert row to int  
                     GLAcctCode = rows.GLAcctCode.ToString(),
                     LineSeq = Convert.ToInt32(rows.LineSeq.ToString()),
                     PrtlAmt = Convert.ToDouble(rows.PrtlAmt.ToString()),
                     PortalDocNum = rows.PrtlDocNum.ToString(),
                     PrtlFinRptDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rows.PrtlFinRptDate.ToString()),
                     PrtlTranDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rows.PrtlTranDate.ToString()),
                     PrtlUniqueID = rows.PrtlUniqueID.ToString(),
                     StmntAmt = Convert.ToDouble(rows.StmntAmt.ToString()),
                     StmntDocNum = rows.StmntDocNum.ToString(),
                     StmntEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rows.StmntEndDate.ToString()),
                     StmntTranDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rows.StmntTranDate.ToString()),

                 }).ToList();
        return _pvtrecon;
}

}
```

And here is the associated View

```
     @model IEnumerable<C1MvcWebApplication1.Models.Recon>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It throws a 404 error when I enter localhost/Recon/Load.
When I look at the actual code for the view I am getting an error in `Line 1 Column 1  "Syntax error, '>' expected`

I know I am only trying to display one of my elements right now in the view, but I listed all items in the called class in the controller in case there is a syntax issue there that is rolling over.  `ReconUIDataLayer.UIDataLayer.LoadRecon` is being called from a DLL I have attached in References.

Comment: Did you try to pass an empty list to your view from the controller, by commenting out the line that calls GetList() ?

Comment: I did, it did not matter

Comment: I don't see any errors. Have you stepped through the code? Try adding code into your view and putting a stop in it. `  @MvcHtmlString.Create("<br />")`  This will ensure you are calling the correct view.

Comment: Is the issue the controller itself?  I added a simple ActionResult Index(),  added an index view and set the return to go to the index page.  It gives the same 404 error.   When I add a completely new controller with a simple ActionResult of going to a page it works fine

Comment: Neer, where in the view do I put this?

Comment: have you tried making `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` into `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: Not sure that changes something, but you don't have to specify the first parameter "Load" of your return statement, it could be `return View(_recon);`

Comment: Otherwise I would suggest you add back every part of your Load view to the one that's working and see when it starts to crash...if it does.

Comment: I stared at this a bit more and wonder if the `@model IEnumerable<C1MvcWebApplication1.Models.Recon>` might perhaps be `@model List<C1MvcWebApplication1.Models.Recon>` as shown in the controller perhaps? - it is pointing to that line as it compiles the view.  I also once had an issue with VS and had to restart Visual Studio with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS far as I can tell, the issue was basically some kind of caching issue. I shut down VS and reopened solution and it is working fine now.